# C++ Passing Operator as Parameter

Tags: c++

Having trouble finding any resources on this.

```
struct Beta {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    Beta(int aFoo, int aBar) : foo(aFoo), bar(aBar) {}

    operator Alpha() const { return Alpha(foo, bar); }
}
struct Alpha {
    float foo;
    float bar;
    Alpha(float aFoo, float aBar) : foo(aFoo), bar(aBar) {}
}
```

And now I have:

```
vector<Beta> betas;
vector<Alpha> alphas;
transform(beta.begin(), beta.end(), back_inserter(alphas), &Beta.operator Alpha());
```

But this fails so I'm wondering the proper way to do it.

Comment: Nope I read that backward. My apologies.

Comment: [Please post real code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please confirm goal: Copy `betas` to `alphas`? Nothing fancy?

Comment: While what OP tried to do, I think, is impossible, I believe what they want to do is worth unlocking and answering... If they clean up the question.

Comment: @user4581301 Here you go,

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. I'm a bit slow though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most readable solution is just to use a lambda. Below is a complete example:

```
#include <algorithm>

struct Alpha {
    float foo;
    float bar;
    Alpha(float aFoo, float aBar) : foo(aFoo), bar(aBar) {}
};

struct Beta {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    Beta(int aFoo, int aBar) : foo(aFoo), bar(aBar) {}

    operator Alpha() const { return Alpha(foo, bar); }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Beta> betas;
    std::vector<Alpha> alphas;
    std::transform(betas.begin(), betas.end(), back_inserter(alphas), [](Beta b) { return Alpha(b); });
}
```

If you insist that you want to explicitly bind the operator instead, or just want to see what that syntax looks like, use this instead: For me with GCC and optimizations turned on, this yields *exactly* the same assembly output as the lambda version above:

```
using namespace std::placeholders; // For _1
std::transform(betas.begin(), betas.end(), back_inserter(alphas), std::bind(&Beta::operator Alpha, _1));
```

Comment: Thanks I knew the first one and kinda was just wondering what the syntax looked like. Thanks so much for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you tried is not possible in C++. You can insert a layer of abstraction (Call a function that calls the operator), but someone's beaten me to that option. So let's look at `Alpha` knowing how to construct itself based on `Beta` instead.

```
struct Alpha
{
    ...
    // construct an Alpha from a Beta
    Alpha(const Beta& source) :
            foo(source.foo), bar(source.bar)
    {
    }
};
```

Now you can [use `std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) to construct `Alpha`s from `Beta`s.

```
alphas.insert(alphas.begin(), betas.begin(), betas.end());
```

Full code with test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Beta
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
    Beta(int aFoo, int aBar) :
            foo(aFoo), bar(aBar)
    {
    }
};

struct Alpha
{
    float foo;
    float bar;
    Alpha(float aFoo, float aBar) :
            foo(aFoo), bar(aBar)
    {
    }
    Alpha(const Beta& source) :
            foo(source.foo), bar(source.bar)
    {
    }

};

int main()
{
    vector<Beta> betas
    {
      { 1, 1 },
      { 2, 2 },
      { 3, 3 } 
    };

    vector<Alpha> alphas;
    alphas.insert(alphas.begin(), betas.begin(), betas.end());
    for (const Alpha & a : alphas)
    {
        std::cout << a.foo << ',' << a.bar << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that while simpler, this might not be a viable option. Alpha may not know of the existence of Beta.